# In which Banach spaces of functions do the convergence almost everywhere and boundedness of norms imply the weak convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

See the title.

If I am not mistaken, this is true for $L^2$-spaces but is false for $L^1$-spaces. Say, should the space be reflexive?

Comment: For $1<p<\infty$.${}{}$

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442550/pointwise-convergence-and-boundedness-in-norm-imply-weak-convergence?rq=1) for an outline of a proof that you'll have weak convergence in $L_p$, $1<p<\infty$ with your conditions. In $L_1$, $f_n=n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ furnishes a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, thanks. My aim is an abstract property for much more general spaces of functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you only speak about the spaces $L^p(0,1)$, $1 \le p \le \infty$, this is *always* false.

Just consider the sequence
\begin{equation*}
 u_n(t) =
 \begin{cases}
  n^{1/p} & \text{for }t \le 1/n \\
  0 & \text{else},
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
with $n^{1/\infty} = 1$.
Then you have $\|u\|_p^p = \int_0^1 u_n(t)^p \, \mathrm{d}t = 1$ and
$u_n(t) \to 0$ for all $t > 0$.

Hence, $u_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I meant the weak convergence.